# Выводить новость, если дата сегодняшняя

Tags: javascript

Есть список новостей:

```
<ul class="news">
<h3>News</h3>
<li>
<h4>28.07 15.00 – 18.00</h4>
Новость 1
</li>
<li>
<h4>29.07 22.30</h4>
Новость 2
</li>
</ul>
```

Проходимся по списку и находим сегодняшнюю дату:

```
$('.news').each(function(){
        var ddd = $(this).find('li');
        ddd.find('h4').each(function(){
        var current = $(this);  
        var string = current.text();
        var last = string.substring(0, 5);
            if(today == last){
                alert('good');
                console.log(ddd.text());
            }else{
                alert('bad');
            }
    });
});
```

И если дата сегодняшняя выводим новость, не могу догнать, как вывести новость которая в сегодняшней дате?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.news').each(function(){
        var ddd = $(this).find('li');
        ddd.find('h4').each(function(){
        var current = $(this);  
        var string = current.text();
        var last = string.substring(0, 5);
            if(today == last){
                console.log(current.parent().text());
            }
    });
});
```